# Error al consultar base de datos Sqlite en android

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, android-sqlite, operador

He formulado una consulta a la base de datos pero solo tengo acceso a la
primera condición y la segunda no lo reconoce, quiero saber si el operador "or" esta bien implementado y si me dan algunos ejemplos. Gracias

```
String[] parametros = {dueño.getText().toString(), makina.getText().toString(), campoCode.getTe
        xt().toString(), campoIngreso.getText().toString()};

try

{
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM "

            + Utilidades.TABLA_INGRESOS + " WHERE ((" + Utilidades.CAMPO_DUEÑO + "=? AND "

            + Utilidades.CAMPO_MAkINA + "=? AND " + Utilidades.CAMPO_CODE + "=? ) OR ("

            + Utilidades.CAMPO_DUEÑO + "=? AND " + Utilidades.CAMPO_MAkINA + "=? AND "

            + Utilidades.CAMPO_INGRESO + "=? ))", parametros);
```

Comment: Esta bien implementada pero ¿a que te refieres que la segunda no te la reconoce ?.

Comment: Es extraño ya que es un OR , me parece que el problema debe estar relacionado a que tu consulta no es correcta, el tipo de dato por ejemplo que envias a CAMPO_INGRESO será el correcto? @EnemigLuiz

Comment: Si es estraño pero he provado que si funciona cuando los campos a buscar no los pongo en el array "parametros" ,sino los ejecuto directo en el rawQuery . Pero me es necesario que estos campos esten en el array.          Haber si tiene alguna solucion esto.